# Scroll to position conditional for tablet and mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, target, scrolltop

I have the following first part working perfectly which scrolls to the top (allowing for a fixed navigation) and stops 155px from top of page. However as we come down to tablet the header drops to 75px depth and then to 65px on mobile.

Is there a way to conditionally scroll to a different position based on the css height of the nav bar? The commented out section is what I've been playing with.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

            var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

            if( target.length ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top)-155
                }, 1000);
            }

            // else if ( $(".dl-menuwrapper button").css("height") === "65px") {
            //     $('html, body').animate({
            //         scrollTop: (target.offset().top)-75
            //     }, 1000);
            // }

        });
```

Anybody have any ideas so I can get this working with an additional two heights for tablet and mobile?

Comment: get the width of window. $( window ).width(); if it is less-than 768px do -75px else -155px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the height of the nav-bar as a variable, that way it doesn't matter what device is used.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $( $(this).attr('href') ),
            navBarHeight = $(".nav").height();

        if( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: (target.offset().top) - navBarHeight
            }, 1000);
        }

    });
```

Obviously, change `$(".nav")` to use the correct selector for your purpose.  You could also add an offset by adding a constant to `navBarHeight`.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, it's an elegant solution and working perfectly!